# Binomial probabilities under different sample sizes

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, binomial-distribution

I have a question about the binomial distribution probabilities, more like a curiosity that I couldn't prove.

Let $n_1<n_2$ and let $X_1\sim Bin(n_1,0.5), X_2\sim Bin(n_2,0.5)$. Suppose that $n_1,n_2$ are even positive integers, for simplicity.

We know that $P(X_1=\frac{n_1}{2})>P(X_2=\frac{n_2}{2})$, that is, the probability of $X_1$ assuming its most probable value is greater than the probability of $X_2$ assuming its most probable value. We could use stochastic dominance to justify this, or even prove it by comparing the probability values themselves.

My question is, does this logic applies to values that further away from the distribution mode? For example, is it true that:

$$P(X_1=\frac{n_1}{2}-1)>P(X_2=\frac{n_2}{2}-1)$$

That is, is it true that the probability of $X_1$ assuming its second most probable value is greater than the probability of $X_2$ assuming its second most probable value? Or more generally:

$$P(X_1=\frac{n_1}{2}-k)>P(X_2=\frac{n_2}{2}-k), k\leq \frac{n_1}{2}$$

Comment: The most probable value of a binomial($n$,$p$) distribution is the mode, i.e. $\lfloor(n+1)p \rfloor$ or $\lceil(n+1)p\rceil-1$. What you've written doesn't seem to correspond to that; to see why, consider $p$ very close to 0 or 1.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of p=0.5, I hadn't realized I wrote generic p, thanks for the comment

Comment: Try writing the events as $X_1 \sim Binom(2t,0.5)$ and $X_2 \sim Binom(2t + 2j, 0.5)$ for $m\in\{2,4,6,...\}$. The event of interest is $X_1 = t$ and $X_2 = t+j$ where $j > 0$.

Comment: If you would plot the probability mass functions for two simple examples I think you would immediately see the answer.